# Error in uploading data in QGIS cloud

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, error, qgis-cloud

I want to publish my .shp file using QGIS Cloud plugin.

I signed in to qgiscloud.com (free). On create new database it will auto create dbname='fbeudp_mfaphk' user='fbeudp_mfaphk' password='68456287' on host='spacialdb.com' port='9999'.

I am unable to change the dbname, user or password (no option is given). On uploading this (.shp)file, an error is showing like this:
 [image: error msg]

Windows firewall is off. I am using QGIS 1.8.0.

My question is: How can I remove this error, so that I can publish my file or map on QGIS cloud (website). Is it possible to change the dbname?  If yes, How?, Why my account not shown any created db i.e. dbname='fbeudp_mfaphk'.
 [image: qgis account]

Comment: Buen Dia, Tengo el mismo problema, por favor quien pueda solucionarlo, le agradezco. Google Translate:
Good Day, I have the same problem, please who can fix it, thank you.