# Cannot load layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, server

Whenever I open QGIS (Ver. 2.18.3) and QGIS starts loading layers it stops and shows a error box saying:

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x00000274c/10060.)
>   Is the server running on "spacialdb.com"(144.76104.239) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 9999.

(see screenshot). A username and a password is visible but I have not created them! The fault just came from time to time. What worries me, is that google warns against entering www.spacialdb.com! [image]

Comment: spacialdb is the problem the connection just times out (unresponsive).

Comment: Ok thanks. But what is spacialdb. I´m sort of a newbie in QGIS.

Comment: its a QGIS Cloud plugin. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57585/error-in-uploading-data-in-qgis-cloud/68920